# Timeout on large sql Select

Tags: c#, sql, performance, select

What is the best way to avoid getting timeout on a very large sql select statement?

```
List<int> klienter = FundneKlienter.Keys.ToList();

if (klienter.Count > 0)
{
    Dictionary<int, String> klientNavne = new Dictionary<int, string>(klienter.Count);
    String sql = "SELECT [0],[1] FROM [Tabel] WHERE [0] IN " + klienter.ToSqlList();

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, _connection))
    using (SqlDataReader sr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        if (sr.HasRows)
            while (sr.Read())
                klientNavne.Add(int.Parse(sr["0"].ToString()), sr["1"].ToString());
```

This "klinter" list can contain all the way op to 7 million ID's that are all 4-5 digets long.

What is the best way to optimize this query?

I get timeouts after 40.000+ ?? I'm new to big SQL statements.

Tell me if you need more code to help me.

Comment: Using string concatenation to construct SQL command is not a good practice. StringBuilder, inside a loop to produce a valid sql command and SQL parameters, is one possible approach to avoid this.

Comment: Even if it has nothing to do with your problem but in all honesty (aside from using indexes in your table): Are you sure you really need all 7 million id's in the memory of the application?  Normally my alarm clocks ring when I see a place in code where such a big list is needed and I ask myself if I can dwindle it down by redoing sqls that would need that list by using joins or subqueries, .... . Not sure about your use case thus asking there if you are sure you really need ALL those 7 million entries in a list inside your application as normally that is overkill.

Comment: This is a good point, and you might have some part right. The thing is like this. I have alot of usercontrols 20-30 that all have some controls. These usercontrols has a select statement Fx "select top 1000" and then the next usercontrol have a select statement Fx "select top 2000", but the 2nd usercontrol cant select anything in the 1st, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to avoid the timeout issue is to add:

```
SqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
```

The [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx) says:

> A value of 0 indicates no limit (an attempt to execute a command will
>   wait indefinitely).

Comment: Is there a good way to avoid this error? Additional information: Internal error: An expression services limit has been reached. Please look for potentially complex expressions in your query, and try to simplify them.

Comment: It is also possible to add a timeout setting in your application config file, which actually make it adjustable, depending on circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Rahul's answer above is a good one... You could also look to optmise your query - think about indexing etc...

Comment: In summary, Rahul is giving you a way to not have the query timeout - ever. This is a good idea and by the sounds of it something you should do. Because you are hitting timeouts, I concluded that your query is running for a long time, which is why I suggested implementing indexing etc as a means to speed it up...

Comment: Thanks i've created some indexes now and its runs alot better now